# Lottie file not aligned as expected

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, lottie

I'm using this [Lottie library](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-ios) to render a Lottie animation in SwiftUI.

This is my Lottie file, as you can see it is flush against the left margin (left aligned):

[image: Lottie animation]

Now I try to load this in my app as follows:

```swift
VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: .zero) {
    LottieView(animation: .named("loading-animation"))
        .playing(loopMode: .loop)
        .frame(height: 40)
}
```

As you can see here below, the Lottie animation isn't right aligned as I wish and is placed somewhere at the center.

[image: Lottie animation]

Not sure why the above code doesn't work as is to align the Lottie animation to the left as if I just use another view with this code (A rectangle for example,) it will be left aligned as expected.

How can I make a Lottie animation view align to the left in SwiftUI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `alignment` on the `VStack` is used to determine how multiple views inside the `VStack` should be aligned to each other, if they have different widths. When the `VStack` only contains one view, it has no effect. The same is true of the `spacing`.

I am guessing that the problem is because the content of the `VStack` (the Lottie animation) is not filling the width of the screen. So the `VStack` and its contents are shown horizontally centered. If you add a border to the `VStack` then you will be able to see exactly what width it has.

To fix, you need to expand the view to fill the width by setting `maxWidth: .infinity`. At the same time, you can decide how you want it aligned within the wider frame. You don't even need the `VStack` if it does not have any other content:

*EDIT* Thanks for making the animation available. I was able to reproduce the problem. Applying `.scaledTofit()` before the `.frame` modifiers gets it working for me:

```swift
LottieView(animation: .named("loading-animation"))
    .playing(loopMode: .loop)
    .scaledToFit()
    .background(.yellow)
    .frame(height: 40)
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
```

[image: Animation]

By examining the JSON file, we can see that the animation has a default size of 320x80. So the code here is maintaining the same aspect ratio but scaling (shrinking) it to fit the height of 40pt.

If you want to stretch the animation and make it wider then this can be done by applying another `scaleEffect` to the scaled-down version. To use the full width of the screen, a `GeometryReader` can be used to measure the available space:

```swift
GeometryReader { proxy in
    let w = proxy.size.width
    let h = proxy.size.height
    let scalingFactor = (w / 320) / (h / 80)
    LottieView(animation: .named("loading-animation"))
        .playing(loopMode: .loop)
        .scaledToFit()
        .background(.yellow)
        .scaleEffect(x: scalingFactor, y: 1, anchor: .leading)
}
.frame(height: 40)
```

[image: Animation]

Comment: That did make the VStack full width, however, the Lottie view was still not aligned to the leading margin for some reason, screenshot: https://prnt.sc/p6uYuAkj0M0F - I gave the Vstack a yellow background. As I increase the height to 80, then it moves closer to the leading margin: https://prnt.sc/wF9amfYrFrVA. 80 is the original size of the animation, not sure if this has something to do with the aspect ratio.

Comment: @ShawnFrank I'm afraid I'm not familiar with `LottieView` and also don't have your animation to test with. As you say, it might be related to aspect ratio - maybe an animation has a fixed aspect ratio, in which case the padding may be internal to the animation itself. You could try removing the `.frame` with the fixed height from the animation and set it on the surrounding container instead, then try applying `.scaledToFill()` to the animation. But I'm just guessing, I'm not able to test it.

Comment: Thanks for trying. Here is the animation: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MTB6QTamiT9OnNyMXXcCbzXoGCo8XVZo/view?usp=sharing if you have time / want to try it. I'll give your other suggestions a shot. Cheers !

Comment: @ShawnFrank Answer updated, hopefully cracked it now.

Comment: @ShawnFrank Answer updated once more to show how the animation can be stretched too.